# Party all week end for my birthday?

Tags: date

Knowing a given date (`11/28/1973`), and supposing I will die when I'm 99, what are the years when my birthday will be a thursday so that I will be able to party all week-end?

Comment: The question as it stands will get only "print xx" answers, since there is no input on which the output is dependant on.

Comment: This adds nothing interesting to existing questions such as [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/day-of-the-week-of-the-next-feb-29th).

Answer (score 0):

js

```
var y = 1973 + 99;
while(y-- > 1973) 4!=new Date('11/23/'+y).getDay()||console.log(y);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

**c#**

```
        var birthdate = new DateTime(1973,11,28);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
        {
            var date = birthdate.AddYears(i);
            if (date.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Thursday))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(date.Year);
            }
        }
```