# Advance Happy New Year, 2016!

Tags: string, date, code-golf

Your input will be a integer between 1970 and 2090 (inclusive), representing a year. Your program should output the next year on which New Years Day falls on the same day of the week as the input year.

**Test Cases:**

Below are the sample inputs and outputs

```
2001 => 2007
2047 => 2058
2014 => 2020
1970 => 1976
1971 => 1982
1977 => 1983
2006 => 2012
```

**20% Bonus:** Output the day of the week of New Years Day

```
2001 => 2007 (Mon)
2047 => 2058 (Tue)
2014 => 2020 (Wed)
1970 => 1976 (Thu)
1971 => 1982 (Fri)
1977 => 1983 (Sat)
2006 => 2012 (Sun)
```

**30% Bonus:** Output `Advance Happy New Year, <year>`

```
2010 => Advance Happy New Year, 2016
```

**50% Bonus:** Do both above bonuses

```
2010 => Advance Happy New Year, 2016 (Fri)
```

Write a program which reads input from STDIN or accepts command line arguments, or a function which takes an argument.

**Note:** Please add a link to test your code if possible.

**Leaderboard:**

```js
    var QUESTION_ID=66656,OVERRIDE_USER=16196;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/66656/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
    body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}#answer-list{padding-right: 100px}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I feel like every single dates challenge requires doing the leap years calculation as a subproblem, and it's getting stale.

Comment: Related: [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/day-of-the-week-of-the-next-feb-29th).

Comment: @xnor If that wasn't the case, it would have been just a +7. I.e. "too broad"

Comment: @EriktheGolfer No. When I wrote that comment, my answer was the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Jelly, 9 bytes

```
%4*3%7+5+
```

This is a monadic chain that takes an integer command-line argument as input. It uses my `(x+5+(x%4)**3%7)` algorithm.

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=JTQqMyU3KzUr&input=&args=MjAwMQ). Although that's the current version of Jelly, it also works in [this version](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/tree/c2781762fda4497f099cf62d6a4a548599a0fa0c), which predates the challenge. (Thanks @Dennis!)

Comment: This is amazing! I can confirm that it works with [this revision](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/tree/c2781762fda4497f099cf62d6a4a548599a0fa0c) of the Jelly interpreter, which predates the challenge.

Answer (score 31):

### Mathematica, <s>45</s> <s>37</s> <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```
#+5[6,6,11][[#~Mod~4]]&
```

Improvements thanks to @MartinBüttner (10 bytes), and @ChipHurst (a further 3 bytes).

Comment: Oh, wow. Nobody seems to have noticed this pattern, but it works out.

Comment: Here's a slightly shorter version: `#+5[6,6,11][[#~Mod~4]]&`

Comment: @ChipHurst very clever with `5[6, 6, 11][[0]]` :)

Answer (score 18):

## CJam, <s>21</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
{_9587Cb=+}
```

@martin found a very simple method!

Try it [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B_%5B5%206_B%5D%3D%2B%7D%0A%0A%3AF%3B%0A2001%20FN%0A2047%20FN%0A2014%20FN%0A1970%20FN%0A1971%20FN%0A1977%20FN%0A2006%20FN).

EDIT: Thanks, Dennis!

Comment: @Mauris Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @Vasu: This code is an anonymous function that implements the same `5 6 6 11` trick used in other answers, but the list is encoded as *"the digits of 9587 in base 12"*.

Comment: Got it thanks. I wanted you to add an explanation so people who checks your answer can understand how it works w.r.t language.

Answer (score 10):

## gs2, 12 bytes

```
V@¶4☻s%☺♀i50
```

Translation of my CJam answer. Encoded in CP437 as usual. [Try it online](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/)!

Comment: The link goes to code that produces 2spooky4me, and if I cut and paste the code above, I get the wrong year: http://imgur.com/VAkXT0k (by "wrong year", I mean I get one year earlier than the intended year)

Comment: I'd forgotten a byte. Try now.

Comment: I edited the link, too.

Comment: Cool, it works now

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 20 bytes (no bonuses)

```
a=>a+[5,6,6,11][a%4]
```

The algorithm by @martin proves to be much smaller, so I went with it.

I chose a mathematical approach because JavaScript tends to be verbose. The code is short enough that bonuses only make it longer.

Here is my previous answer (49 bytes), and my original answer (50 bytes):

`F=(a,b=a)=>((a+--a/4|0)-(b++/4+b|0))%7?F(++a,b):b`

`F=(a,b=a)=>(f=c=>(c--+c/4|0)%7)(a)-f(++b)?F(a,b):b`

They work by taking the year and calculating a number (0-6) to represent the "starting day of year". Because the date range for this challenge is within the range of years that follow simple leap year rules (no skipping on 2000), it's fairly straightforward to calculate. Then it's just a matter of comparing forward to find years that start with the same value. Recursion proved to be the most concise way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
+QC@"♣♠♠♂"Q
```

The four bytes in the string should be `05 06 06 0B`.

EDIT: Thanks, FryAmTheEggman!

EDIT: Thanks, Dennis!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 104 bytes - 50% bonus = 52

```js
y=>eval('for(a=0;a!=(b=(new Date(""+y++)+"").slice(0,3));a=a||b)`Advance Happy New Year, ${y} (`')+b+")"
```

### Explanation

```js
y=>
  eval(`                  // eval enables for loop without {} or return
    for(
      a=0;                // a = first day of input year
      a!=                 // check if the day of the current year is equal to the first
        (b=(new Date(     // b = day of current year
          ""+y++)+"")     // cast everything as strings!
            .slice(0,3)); // the first 3 letters of the date string are the day name
      a=a||b              // set a to the day on the first iteration
    )

      // return the string
      \`Advance Happy New Year, \${y} (\`
  `)+b+")"
```

### Test

```js
var solution = y=>eval('for(a=0;a!=(b=(new Date(""+y++)+"").slice(0,3));a=a||b)`Advance Happy New Year, ${y} (`')+b+")"
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="2001" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(+input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Z80 machine code, 12 bytes

A Z80 procedure to be stored at `0000h`, called with the input in `HL`, and all other registers clear:

```
.org 0000h
              ; Bytes   ; Explanation
  ;---------------------------------------------------------------
  DEC B       ; 05      ; 
  LD B, 6     ; 06 06   ;   
  DEC BC      ; 0B      ;
  LD A, 3     ; 3E 03   ;   A = 3
  AND L       ; A5      ;   A = input & 3
  LD E, A     ; 5F      ;   A = input & 3     DE = input & 3
  LD A, (DE)  ; 1A      ;   A = [input & 3]   DE = input & 3
  LD E, A     ; 5F      ;   A = [input & 3]   DE = [input & 3]
  ADD HL, DE  ; 19      ;   HL = input + offset
  RET         ; C9      ;
```

The first three instructions are "NOPs", but are indexed as data later in the code. Upon returning, the output is in `HL`.

Comment: Yep, I've added it to the post.

Comment: Doesn't look right for years 2097 and 2098, which need additions of 7 and 12, respectively.

Comment: The OP says the input year is guaranteed to be in the 1970-2090 range.

Comment: I really don't like questions that are changed  after I've answered!

Comment: Do you need the `ret`?

Comment: I believe that's how machine code is counted: my code is now a callable subroutine. Not having the ret would mean calculating the value and then crashing or looping forever or something... I'm not sure. It doesn't do anything, but it feels necessary.

Comment: Are you allowed to specify that the input is in `DE` and therefore you can use `LD A, 3; AND E; LD L, A; LD L, (HL);`?

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>140</s> <s>100</s> <s>102</s> <s>84.5</s> 154 * 0.5 = 77 bytes

<s>I could probably write a better solution with Sakamoto's algorithm, but this will do for now</s>

I was right. Here's an implementation using Sakamoto's algorithm.

```
def s(y):
 d=lambda j:(j+j//4)%7
 for i in range(y,y+15):
  if d(i)==d(y-1):return"Advance Happy New Year, %d (%s)"%(-~i,"SMTWTFSuouehranneduit"[d(i)::7])
```

Explanation:

```
def day_of_the_week(year):
    return (year + year//4 - 1 + 0 + 1) % 7
    # The month code for January is 0, and you add 1 from January *1*.
    # The -1 is to correct for starting on Saturday 
    # and so that it cancels out the 1 from January 1.

def new_years(this_year):
# But in Sakamoto's algorithm, if the month is January or February, we must subtract 1.
    weekdays = "SunMonTueWedThuFriSat"
    for item in range(this_year, this_year + 15):
        if day_of_the_week(this_year - 1) == day_of_the_week(item):
            day = weekdays[day_of_the_week(item)*3 : day_of_the_week(item)*3+3]
            return "Advance Happy New Year, %d (%s)"%(item + 1, day)
        # So we subtract from every year we check, including this_year
        # And add 1 back in at the end
        # And print the greeting, the year, and the corresponding day of the week
```

Comment: I have updated the question. You need not check for century years.

Comment: How about `w="SMTWTFSuouehranneduit"` and then printing `w[d(i)::7]`?

Answer (score 4):

### Seriously, <s>35</s> 17 bytes

`[5,6,6,11]` trick saves the day.

```
4,;)%[5,6,6,11]E+
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=342c3b29255b352c362c362c31315d452b&input=2047)

Explanation:

```
4,;)%[5,6,6,11]E+
4,;)%              push input, input % 4
     [5,6,6,11]E   push (input % 4)th element of [5,6,6,11]
                +  add to the input
```

Old version:

```
,;;D`45/*≈7@%`;╝ƒ╗35*r+`╛ƒ╜=`M1@íu+
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c3b3b446034352f2af7374025603bbc9fbb33352a722b60be9fbd3d604d3140a1752b&input=2047)

Explanation:

```
,;;D`45/*≈7@%`;╝ƒ╗35*r+`╛ƒ╜=`M1@íu+
,;;                                  push 3 copies of the input (n)
   D                                 decrement the top copy of n
    `45/*≈7@%`;╝                     push Sakamoto's algorithm as a function and save a copy in register 1
                ƒ╗                   call Sakamoto's algorithm function and save result in register 0
                  35*r+              push [n, n+1, ..., n+14]
                       `    `M       map the function:
                        ╛ƒ╜=           push Sakamoto's algorithm, call, push 1 if equal to value in register 0 else 0
                              1@í    get the index of the first 1
                                 u+  increment and add n
```

Sakamoto's algorithm:

```
45/*≈7@%
45/*      multiply by 5/4
    ≈     floor
     7@%  mod 7
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, 31 bytes

Following the edit to the question that restricts the input range to 1970-2090, this becomes pretty trivial:

```
f(x){return"\5\6\6\13"[x%4]+x;}
```

Without the non-leap century years, there's a simple 5,6,6,11 sequence of intervals for the first repeat of the same day.

Complete solution to original problem (not constrained to 2090), 90 bytes:

```
f(x){return(x-1)%100>89&&(x+9)/100%4?"\6\14\5\6\6\6\6\7\14\6"[x%10]+x:"\5\6\6\13"[x%4]+x;}
```

#### Test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv)
        printf("Advance Happy New Year, %d\n", f(atoi(*argv)));
    return !argc;
}
```

## Test run:

```
$ ./66656 2001 2047 2014 1970 1971 1977 2006
Advance Happy New Year, 2007
Advance Happy New Year, 2058
Advance Happy New Year, 2020
Advance Happy New Year, 1976
Advance Happy New Year, 1982
Advance Happy New Year, 1983
Advance Happy New Year, 2012
```

Answer (score 4):

### R, <s>143</s> 136 * 0.5 = 68 bytes

```
G=function(y)strftime(paste(y,1,1,sep='-'),'%a')
d=seq(y<-scan(),y+14);sprintf("Advance Happy New Year, %i (%s)",d[G(d)==(w=G(y))][2],w)
```

Use `%A` for full day name instead of `%a, depend on desired state.

### R, 120 * 0.7 = 84 bytes

```
G=function(y)as.POSIXlt(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j")$wday
d=seq(y<-scan(),y+14);cat("Advance Happy New Year,",d[G(d)==G(y)][2])
```

### R, 90 bytes

```
G=function(y)as.POSIXlt(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j")$wday
d=seq(y<-scan(),y+14);d[G(d)==G(y)][2]
```

---

All answers above are derivative work based on @plannapus answer. 
Using the `;` separator to avoid needing to `source` the file or run it as script on command line.

Comment: +1 I completely forgot about `weekdays`, nice.

Comment: @plannapus Thanks :) (I counted the newlines, asked the file system in fact, as I'm under windows it's 2 bytes but I've no newline at end which a POSIX file should have, so it's fair to keep it like this actually)

Answer (score 3):

## R, 145 bytes -50% -> 72.5

```
y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%a");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;sprintf("Advance Happy New Year, %i (%s)",x,F(x))
```

Examples:

```
> y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%a");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;sprintf("Advance Happy New Year, %i (%s)",x,F(x))
1: 2006
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Advance Happy New Year, 2012 (Sun)"
> y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%a");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;sprintf("Advance Happy New Year, %i (%s)",x,F(x))
1: 1977
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Advance Happy New Year, 1983 (Sat)"
> y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%a");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;sprintf("Advance Happy New Year, %i (%s)",x,F(x))
1: 2014
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Advance Happy New Year, 2020 (Wed)"
```

### R, 97 bytes (without bonus)

```
y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%w");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;x
```

Indented, with new lines:

```
y = scan() #Takes input from stdin
F = function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%w") #Year to Weekday
x = y+1
while(F(x) != F(y)) x = x+1
x
```

Test cases:

```
> y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%w");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;x
1: 1977
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 1983
> y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%w");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;x
1: 2006
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 2012
> y=scan();F=function(y)format(as.POSIXct(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j"),"%w");x=y+1;while(F(x)!=F(y))x=x+1;x
1: 2016
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 2021
```

Comment: I don't understand this wish of getting on one ugly line, a carriage return is not most costly than a `;` ...

Comment: you can save 1 char by removing the first `y=scan;` and using `x=y<-scan()+1` I think

Comment: and you can save seven more by using `as.POSIXlt(paste(y,1),,"%Y %j")$wday` as your function body

Comment: @Tensibai if you don t put it on one single line and paste it directly to the console, `scan` will read in the second line as the input. `x=y<-scan()+1` with 2014 as stdin will give you x=2015 and y=2015 ( i. e. the assignment is `y <- scan()+1`) and if you try to do  `x=1+y<-scan()` it will give you an error (`Error in 1 + y <- scan() : target of assignment expands to non-language object`) because it's trying to assign `scan()` to `1+y`.

Comment: @Tensibai As for your last advice, the results of `...$wday` is the weekday number: but here i need the weekday name so that i can print `Advance Happy New Year, 2012 (Sun)`

Comment: Indeed the advice was for the no-bonus one. For the scan, as the challenge ask for a program, using source or needing to launch on command line didn't sound a problem for me (and in this case the newline is not a problem) I took the liberty to write an answer based on those comments, if it's a problem tell me, I'll tag it 'community wiki' as it's mainly based on your original idea ;)

Comment: @Tensibai you're more than welcome to write your own answer based on these comments indeed! For the newline vs `;` thingy: as you said, it's equivalent. I'm just choosing `;` 1) by taste and for users who want to quickly check that my code works without any hassle (such as the one i mentioned earlier); 2) as a legacy: [years ago, I add a discussion with another user about newlines](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10659/6741) so i switched to `;` to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 120 <s>139</s> bytes - 50% = 60 bytes

A functional approach:

```
$s=strtotime;for($d=date(D,$s(($y=$argv[1]).$_="-1-1"));$d!=date(D,$s(++$y.$_)););echo"Advance Happy New Year, $y ($d)";
```

Takes one input from command line, like:

```
$ php ahny.php 2001
```

**The OOP way seems to be longer, as always (143 bytes):**

```
$s=strtotime;for($d=date(D,$s($x=($y=$argv[1])."-1-1"));$d!=date(D,$s(++$y."-1-1")););echo"Advance Happy New Year, $y ($d)";
```

**Edits**

- *Saved* **18 bytes**. Instead of adding one year using the PHP modifier `+1year`, I now simply increment the given year.
- *Saved* **1 byte** by storing `-1-1` in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 130 * 0.50 = 65 Bytes

```
Sub k(y)
i=1
Do While Weekday(y+i)<>Weekday(y)
i=i+1
Loop
MsgBox "Advance Happy New Year," &y+i &WeekdayName(Weekday(y+i))
End Sub
```

VBA makes finding week days so easy.... If only it wasn't so Verbose about it.

Answer (score 3):

## C, score <s>53</s> 52 (104 bytes)

```
f(x){x+="0116"[x%4];printf("Advance Happy New Year, %d (%.3s)",x-43,"MonTueWedThuFriSatSun"+x*5/4%7*3);}
```

Idea borrowed from [Toby Speight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66691/25315); added the bonus display of weekday.

Shortened the string by shifting the character codes to a more comfortable range. Had to choose the right shifting amount (e.g. 43) to make the short weekday calculation code `x*5/4%7` work.

Comment: I take it your character code stuff restricts this to ASCII-compatible encodings?

Comment: Yes. The codes should be greater than 31, so the minimal number to add to the codes would be 27, giving the string `" !!&"`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>(1-.2)*323</s> (1-.5)*<s>350</s> <s>348</s> 339  = <s>258.4</s> <s>175</s> <s>174</s> 169.5 bytes

```
import java.text.*;class D{public static void main(String[]a){long y=new Long(a[0]);int i=0;for(;!s(y).equals(s(y+(++i))););System.out.printf("Advance Happy New Year, %d (%s)",y+i,s(y+i));}static String s(long y){try{return new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy").parse("1/1/"+y));}catch(Exception e){}return"";}}
```

Ugh.

Ungolfed:

```
import java.text.*;
class D{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        long y=new Long(a[0]);
        int i=0;
        for(;!s(y).equals(s(y+(++i))););
        System.out.printf("Advance Happy New Year, %i (%s)",y+i,s(y+i));
    }
    static String s(long y){
        try{
            return new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy").parse("1/1/"+y));
        }catch(Exception e){}
        return"";
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/8mltA5)

Thanks to @Kenney for pointing out that I could shorten with `new Long` and `printf`! :D

Comment: `long y=new Long(a[0])` saves 6 (12) bytes, and using `printf` saves another 3 (6).

Answer (score 2):

## GNU coreutils, <strike>52</strike> <strike>51</strike> 49 bytes

(98 bytes program - 50% bonus)

```
seq -f$1-1-1\ %gyear 28|date -f- +'Advance Happy New Year, %Y (%a)'|sed /`date -d$1-1-1 +%a`/!d\;q
```

Input is from command-line argument, and output is to stdout.

#### Explanation

```sh
# generate 28 input years from $1 + 1 onwards (28 is always enough)
seq -f '$1-1-1 %g year' 28
|
# convert all of these as potential outputs
date -f- +'Advance Happy New Year, %Y (%a)'
|
 # Select the first one where the dayname matches that of input year
sed "/`date -d$1-1-1 +%a`/!d;q"
```

#### Test run:

All locale settings can be `C` or `POSIX`.

```
$ for i in 2001 2047 2014 1970 1971 1977 2006; do ./66656.sh $i; done
Advance Happy New Year, 2007 (Mon)
Advance Happy New Year, 2058 (Tue)
Advance Happy New Year, 2020 (Wed)
Advance Happy New Year, 1976 (Thu)
Advance Happy New Year, 1982 (Fri)
Advance Happy New Year, 1983 (Sat)
Advance Happy New Year, 2012 (Sun)
```

Limitation: this only works up to year 2147485519 (though the question is now changed to permit a lower limit).

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 145 * 50% = <s>74</s> <s>73.5</s> 72.5 bytes

```
d=DateValue;StringForm["Advance Happy New Year, `` (``)",NestWhile[#+1&,(a=#)+1,#!=#2&@@DateObject@{{a},{#}}~d~"DayName"&],{a}~d~"DayNameShort"]&
```

Uses standard date functions.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, 23 bytes

```
L%+/b4b7.VQIqyby-Q1+1bB
```

Doesn't qualify for any of the bonuses.

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%25%2B%2Fb4b7.VQIqyby-Q1%2B1bB&input=2006&debug=0).

Similar to the pure python answer.

```
                        - Q = eval(input()) (autoassigned)
L                       - y = lambda b:
   /b4                  - b floordiv 4
  +   b                 - + b
 %     7                - mod 7


        .VQ             - for b in range(Q, infinate):
           Iqyby-Q1     - if y(b) == y(Q-1):
                   +1b  - print b+1
                      B - break
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 28 bytes

```
i0:14+t1tI$YO8H$XO!st1)=f2))
```

#### Example

```
>> matl i0:14+t1tI$YO8H$XO!st1)=f2))
> 1970
1976
```

#### Code explained

```
i           % input year
0:14+       % vector with that year and the next 14
t1tI$YO     % first day of each year
8H$XO       % transform into three letters specifying weekday
!s          % sum those three letters to reduce to unique numbers
t1)         % get first of those numbers (corresponding to input year)
=f2)        % find index of second matching
)           % index with that to obtain output year
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>70</s>  23 bytes

```perl6
{($^a+1...{[==] ($a,$_).map: {Date.new(:year($_)).day-of-week}})[*-1]} # 70 bytes
```

```perl6
{($_ X+5,6,6,11)[$_%4]} # 23 bytes
```

usage:

```perl6
for «2001 2047 2014 1970 1971 1977 2006 2010» {
  printf "%d => %d\n", $_, {($_ X+5,6,6,11)[$_%4]}( $_ )
}
```

```perl6
2001 => 2007
2047 => 2058
2014 => 2020
1970 => 1976
1971 => 1982
1977 => 1983
2006 => 2012
2010 => 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
%4=0,3×-,5S++6
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=JTQ9MCwzw5ctLDVTKys2&input=&args=MjAwMA)

Until today, Jelly had no array indexing, so the above will have to do. Since the latest commit, array indexing has been implemented as `ị`, giving the following solution (**10 bytes**).

```
ị6,6,11,5+
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4buLNiw2LDExLDUr&input=&args=MjAwMA)

Comment: I think Jelly can spare 7 characters for 10~16 constants.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 14 bytes

```
+5 6 6 11{~4&|
```

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 12 bytes

```
U+"♣♠♠♂"cU%4
```

As with the Pyth answer, the four bytes in the string should be `05 06 06 0B`. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VSsiBQYGCyJjVSU0&input=MjAwMQ==)

```
U+"♣♠♠♂"cU%4  // Implicit: U = input integer
  "♣♠♠♂"      // Take this string.
        cU%4  // Take the char code at U%4.
U+            // Add U.
              // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: Thanks for this Christmas gift of a bounty! But can someone tell me how I earned it?

Comment: I looked through the history. Apparently the OP attempted to bounty an answer, but forgot to award the bounty, so Community chose to pass half the reputation onto this answer (I think it bases its choice on recent upvotes).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 35 bytes

```
Iq%Q4 3=+Q11).?Iq%Q4 0=+Q5).?=+Q6;Q
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Iq%25Q4+3%3D%2BQ11%29.%3FIq%25Q4+0%3D%2BQ5%29.%3F%3D%2BQ6%3BQ&input=2001&debug=0)

Comment: [32 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Iq3%25Q4%3D%2BQ11%29.%3FIq0%25Q4%3D%2BQ5%29.%3F%3D%2BQ6Q&input=2001&debug=0).

Comment: [18 bytes now](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%25Q4%2B%3Fq3J11%3FqJZ5+6&input=2001&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## C# (6.0) .Net Framework 4.6 173 Bytes - 30% = 121.1 Bytes

```
void n(int y)=>Console.Write($"Advance Happy New Year, {Enumerable.Range(1,15).Select(i=>new DateTime(y+i,1,1)).First(x=>x.DayOfWeek==new DateTime(y,1,1).DayOfWeek).Year}");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript ES7, 17 bytes

```
a=>a+5+(a%4)**3%7
```

It's my first time using JS. I found this using a Python script, and I believe it to be optimal. It works because `0**3` is 0 mod 7, `1**3` and `2**3` are both 1, and `3**3` is 6.

Comment: Isn't the [Exponentiation Operator `**`](https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator) an *ES7* feature? Or are you using [Babel](https://babeljs.io)?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 23 bytes

```
lambda a:a+5+(a%4)**3%7
```

A port of my JavaScript answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

```
++5%^%Q4 3 7
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2B5%25%5E%25Q4+3+7&input=2001&test_suite_input=2001%0A2047%0A2014%0A1977&debug=0)** or **[Check out the Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2B5%25%5E%25Q4+3+7&input=2001&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2001%0A2047%0A2014%0A1977&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 18 bytes

This second approach is mainly a golf of [@wizzwizz4's Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67510/59487).

```
J%Q4+?q3J11?qJZ5 6
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%25Q4%2B%3Fq3J11%3FqJZ5+6&input=2001&debug=0)** or **[Check out the Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%25Q4%2B%3Fq3J11%3FqJZ5+6&input=2001&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2001%0A2047%0A2014%0A1977&debug=0)**

---

## Explanation

```
++5%^%Q4 3 7Q  - Q means evaluated input and is implicit at the end.

     %Q4       - Input mod 4.
    ^    3     - Cubed.
   %       7   - Mod 7.
 +5            - Plus 5
+           Q  - Plus the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
4%³7%+5+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTQlMjUlQzIlQjM3JTI1JTJCNSUyQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTIwMDElMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAyMDA3JTBBMjA0NyUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDIwNTglMEEyMDE0JTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMjAyMCUwQTE5NzAlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAxOTc2JTBBMTk3MSUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDE5ODIlMEExOTc3JTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMTk4MyUwQTIwMDYlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAyMDEyJmZsYWdzPUM=)

Port of lirtosiast's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
4%³7%+5+  # Implicit input
4%        # Input mod 4
  ³       # Cubed
   7%     # Mod 7
     +5+  # Plus 5 plus input
          # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
4%¿çƑ{ç¿i+  # Implicit input
4%          # Input mod 4
        i   # Indexed into
  ¿çƑ{ç¿    # The list [5,6,6,11]
         +  # Added to the input
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
4%3e7%+5+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJ+IiwiIiwiNCUzZTclKzUrIiwiIiwiMjAwMSA9PiAyMDA3XG4yMDQ3ID0+IDIwNThcbjIwMTQgPT4gMjAyMFxuMTk3MCA9PiAxOTc2XG4xOTcxID0+IDE5ODJcbjE5NzcgPT4gMTk4M1xuMjAwNiA9PiAyMDEyIl0=)

Port of lirtosiast's Jelly answer.

*-2 thanks to @lyxal*

##### Explanation

```python
4%3e7%+5+  # Implicit input
4%         # Input mod 4
  3e       # Cubed
    7%     # Mod 7
      +5+  # Plus 5 plus input
           # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
4%»&ṗ»12τi+  # Implicit input
4%           # Input mod 4
         i   # Indexed into
  »&ṗ»12τ    # The list [5,6,6,11]
          +  # Added to the input
             # Implicit output
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJ+IiwiIiwiNCUzZTclKzUrIiwiIiwiMjAwMSA9PiAyMDA3XG4yMDQ3ID0+IDIwNThcbjIwMTQgPT4gMjAyMFxuMTk3MCA9PiAxOTc2XG4xOTcxID0+IDE5ODJcbjE5NzcgPT4gMTk4M1xuMjAwNiA9PiAyMDEyIl0=) for 9 bytes porting Jelly. Smh making long answers like this.

Comment: @lyxαl thanks. And we were talking the other day about how you don't have a monograph for "cube" lol

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 32 bytes

```
x=input()
print[5,6,6,11][x%4]+x
```

Uses the `5 6 6 11` trick.

Answer (score 0):

## 2, 12 chars / 18 bytes (non-competitive)

```
ï+⟨566ḋ[ï%4]
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=2001&code=%C3%AF%2B%E2%9F%A8566%E1%B8%8B%5B%C3%AF%254%5D)</kbd>

## Explanation

```
ï+⟨566ḋ[ï%4] // implicit: ï = input, ḋ = 11
ï+           // add ï to:
  ⟨566ḋ      // [5,6,6,11]
       [ï%4] // get index at input mod 4
```